# how to retrieve image from library image picker android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, image-gallery

excuse me i want to ask how to retrieve image from this library?

https://github.com/akshay2211/PixImagePicker

i don't know how to retrieve image from that library. i want to show on my main activity.
i have been try from guide add this code

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == RequestCode) {
                ArrayList<String> returnValue = data.getStringArrayListExtra(Pix.IMAGE_RESULTS);
        }
    }
```

and this is my source code for retrieve image using glide

```
 for (int i = 0; i < returnValue.size(); i++) {
            String path = returnValue.get(i);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(path);
            builder.deleteCharAt(0);
            File file = new File(builder.toString());
            Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(imageUri)
                    .onlyRetrieveFromCache(true)
                    .into(imageView);

            System.out.println("value : " + returnValue.get(i));
            //LoadImageFromWebOperations(returnValue.get(i));
        }
```

and i will always get error like this

```
W/Glide: Load failed for file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20191116_110843.jpg with size [1080x1542]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
```

Comment: Wel tell what you received in that arraylist to begin with. The value of those strings please.

Comment: From the source code, it contains a list of image urls: ```ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Img i : selectionList) {
      list.add(i.getUrl());
      // Log.e("Pix images", "img " + i.getUrl());
    }
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(IMAGE_RESULTS, list);```  So you'll need to load the images from the urls.

Comment: @blackapps i don't get anything from that i try 

for (int i = 0; i < returnValue.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("value" + returnValue.get(i));
                but nothing result from that
            }

Comment: @blackapps i put my code on post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   for (int i = 0; i < returnValue.size(); i++) {
        String path = returnValue.get(i);

        System.out.println ( "path: " + path);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(path)
                .onlyRetrieveFromCache(true)
                .into(imageView);

        break; // load only one image in the imageview
     }
```

Please tell the value of `path`.

```
   .onlyRetrieveFromCache(true)
```

I dont know if that is correct.

In manifest you need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And you should have added code to ask the user at runtime to confirm that permission.

What is the value of `returnValue.size()` ?

Comment: returnValue.size() is length of arraylist.
and path is path location of file like /storage/filename.jpg

Answer (score 0):

From the source code, it contains a list of image urls: 
Source: https://github.com/akshay2211/PixImagePicker/blob/master/pix/src/main/java/com/fxn/pix/Pix.java

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
for (Img i : selectionList) 
{ list.add(i.getUrl()); // Log.e("Pix images", "img " + i.getUrl());
 } 
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(); resultIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(IMAGE_RESULTS, list);
```

So you'll need to iterate through the list of urls and load the corresponding image.

The following is one such method:

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
```

}

Comment: so i  need to add LoadImageFromWebOperations on result activity? and then i can load to grid view?

Comment: im using this but still didn't get any return from that picker

`for (int i = 0; i < returnValue.size(); i++) {
                //System.out.println("value" + returnValue.get(i));
                LoadImageFromWebOperations(returnValue.get(i));
            }`